# prometheus not starting (not loading prometheus.yml file)

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

while starting Prometheus I'm getting the following error:

```
level=error ts=2021-05-13T04:42:39.652Z caller=main.go:355 msg="Error loading config (--config.file=prometheus.yml)" err="parsing YAML file prometheus.yml: yaml: line 36: did not find expected key"
```

I was trying to integrate Blackbox Exporter to Prometheus.

This is my `prometheus.yml` file:

```yaml
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any time-series scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9100']



  - job_name: 'blackbox_exporter'
     metrics_path: /probe
     params:
       module: [http_2xx]
     static_configs:
       - targets:
           - https://www.google.in
     relabel_configs:
       - source_labels: [__address__]
         target_label: __param_target
       - source_labels: [__param_target]
         target_label: instance
       - target_label: __address__
         replacement: localhost:9115
```

Comment: Were u able to resolve this issue?
If yes please share how u did it..

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
promtool check config your_config.yml
```

For rules files use `check rules` instead.

For alertmanager config files use `amtool check-config alertmanager.yml`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run this command to check the configuration

`prometheus --config.file=your_config.yml`

Comment: Isn't this the command to start Prometheus?  It will display the error but also lots of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem,then i add `--config.file=/etc/bitnami/prometheus/prometheus.yml` to set the  config file path when start the container